# Minimum value of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, algebra-precalculus

For $x \in [0, 5]$, let $$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{5}\frac{1}{|x - i|}.$$
Why is $$f(x) \geq 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} = f(0)?$$
This of course is true if one simply plots the graph of $f$. However, how does one verify analytically (i.e. without using the graph)?

[image]

I should clarify that I agree that one can split the function up into 5 pieces and consider each piece. Is there a way that is easier to generalise to something like 1000 functions that isn't case by case?

Comment: As usual, using derivatives and endpoints.

Comment: Are there any other ways, this seems mildly tedious (albeit doable) if let's say I had 1000 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be working for the general case.

Given a fixed positive integer $n$ and let
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{|x - i|}
\end{equation}
for all $x\in[0,n]-\{0,1,\dots,n\}.$

Put any $x\in[0,n]-\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Then there exists an integer $0\le k<n$ such that $k<x<k+1$. If $k\ge 1$ we have,
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{k}\frac{1}{x-i} + \sum_{i = k+1}^{n}\frac{1}{i-x}\\
&> \sum_{i = 1}^{k}\frac{1}{k+1-i} + \sum_{i = k+1}^{n}\frac{1}{i-k}\\
&=\left(\frac1k+\dots+1\right)+\left(1+\dots+\frac1{n-k}\right)\\
&> \left(\frac1k+\dots+1\right)+\left(\frac1{k+1}+\dots+\frac1{n}\right)\\
&=f(0).
\end{align}
And if $k=0$ then \begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{i-x}> \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=f(0)\end{equation}
which is also true.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** - Divide it into $5$ functions and check the derivative of each one of them separately:

- $x\in(0,1):f_1(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{3-x}+\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{5-x}$
- $x\in(1,2):f_2(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{3-x}+\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{5-x}$
- $x\in(2,3):f_3(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{3-x}+\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{5-x}$
- $x\in(3,4):f_4(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{5-x}$
- $x\in(4,5):f_5(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{1}{x-4}+\frac{1}{5-x}$

Comment: While I agree this is a way to do this, is there a way to make this general? What if I had 1000 functions?

Comment: @user37221: Note that each function can be divided into two "$\sum$"s. This should allow you to define a "general case" function.

Comment: Right, so I have: Let $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n - 1\}$. For each $x \in (n, n + 1)$, then $f = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(k - x)^{-1} + \sum_{k = n + 1}^{N}(x - k)^{-1}$. Taking a derivative gives a critical point, however, how do I know the value of $f$ at this critical point is $> f(0)$?